# Fully Explore a Minecraft Map Without Having To Physically Explore It

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently created a Creative Minecraft world and I needed to explore all of the 4 zoom levels of a map item. Is there a way I can do this without actually having to go and physically fly around it? EG: an NBT Value? Or maybe something with MCEdit?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms I mean this: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Map#Zoom_out

Comment: Command blocks that teleport you through the chunks until you reach the border? Pretty sure I found a video a while ago...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether we are talking about a multiplayer server or a single player world the answer is mixed.  Map data is created once the area is loaded around the map so you would need to either explore that area or use some form of an auto mover/camera tool to move through the area.  That aside here is some information that may help a bit with trying to do this as efficiently as possible:

On a *multiplayer* server the view distance on most servers is normally set to about 8 chunks or 128x128 blocks which is the same size as a map with no zoom step (1:1).  The max that a server owner can set their server for is 15 chunks or 240x240 blocks which would actually fall one chunk (16 blocks) short around the entire border when viewed on a map with zoom step of +1 (1:2).  Beyond this, you would have to load the chunks with the map via actual movement within the area.

On a *single player* world you could use a tool similar to [Optifine](http://optifine.net) which allows you to set your view distance beyond the normal limits of 16 chunks to a "extreme" view distance of 32 chunks or 512x512 blocks.  With this view distance on a map with zoom step 4 (1:16) you could fully load the map with as few a four perfectly spaced passes through the area.  Of course with the game trying to load this much data all at once the time savings may be negated if you are not doing this on a fair powerful system that can process and load all these chunks quickly.

Answer (score 1):

[WorldPainter (link)](http://www.worldpainter.net/)

---

"WorldPainter is an interactive map generator for Minecraft. It allows you to "paint" landscapes using similar tools as a regular paint program. Sculpt and mould the terrain, paint materials, trees, snow and ice, etc. onto it, and much more."

It will let you custom make your terrain, even better!

---

### McEdit (Simple):

1. Create New World

   - Generator: Minecraft Server
   - Set Size to generate: East-West by North-South in chunks (1 chunk = 16 blocks)
2. Create and wait
3. Save and close
4. Done

   Note:

You may have to add the **[minecraft_server.jar (link)](https://minecraft.net/download)**.  So that you can use the latest version of minecraft in your terrain generation

### Worldedit (complex):

Using the worldedit plugin:

You can select a region using: //pos1, //pos2 at the corners of the region

Then using the command: //regen

This will remove then generate all of the chunks in the region.

Caution: this will cause lots of lag,  I recommend doing this on a bukkit server and not use it while the process is running.

Comment: I thought you meant the chunks not the item map, nevermind... I think there is a mcedit plugin but you would have to go out looking for it.  However map data is not stored in NBT on the item, its stored in the world save.  That is how you can spawn multiple of the same maps.

Comment: Map data IS stored in NBT format on the map item, but the data is only generated for the map after the map is created.  This is why you need to enter within a "viewable" distance of all the areas of the map before it adds the tag data to the map item.

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Data_values#Maps

The mars are stored in separate .dat files and then linked via meta, there is no NBT stored on the map it's self other than meta values

Comment: I was mistaken in that comment, however, map data is stored in NBT format but in it's own linked data file.